# How to stop event specified in a4j:support on certain conditions?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have a4j:support inside a certain component.
What i wanted to do is to disable the sending of ajax request on the component on certain conditions.
How can i disable a4j:support/a4j:ajax not to fire the ajax request on that component.
Let say for example a certain click on that component.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return false on the submit event of a4j:support:

```
<a4j:support id="myField"
             event="onblur" 
             onsubmit="if(valid()==false){return false;}" 
             oncomplete="complete();" 
             actionListener="#{myBacking.myAction}" 
             reRender="myOtherFields" />
```

valid() returns true or false, if it returns true, you do nothing (don't return true).

Comment: Can i use EL inside the onsubmit attribute for example. onsubmit="if(#{bean.isTrue} == false) {return false;}". Or is there any way around. I wanted to check the property from the bean. :)

Comment: no, only javascript, but you can put the bean value in a hidden field and access it like this: document.getElementById('myid'), the hidden field must have value="#{bean.isTrue}".